# Linux audio driver and ALSA (external) clock selection

Tags: linux, audio, alsa

From quality point of view it is desired not to use the clock from a SOC/CPU for audio, but to provide an external clock to the I2S interface. Many I2S interfaces have the option for an external MCLK/BCLK, so that is no problem.

However, for different sample rates, different clock frequencies are required (2 for most common sample rates). This implies there must be a way to select/configure an external clock. From technical point of view, this is not too difficult when customizing a codec driver. I wonder if there are other (generic) methods, which can be used without modifying a driver.

I could not find any info, somebody aware of a standard method ?

Comment: Did you find out anything interesting on this?

Comment: I could not find any info.